# AndroidManifest.xml isnt in Res folder of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I'm following some example and I need to modify the `AndroidManifest.xml` but I don't see it in my project.

How can I find this file?

[image: there isnt androidmanifest.xml]

Comment: Note: For any Android project, it never is in the `res` folder.

Comment: And why do you search it in `res`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click `manifests` and you should see `AndroidManifest.xml` in there.

Double click it and edit accordingly.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Fun fact for all JetBrains IDEs.

Double Shift = Find Everything. Just start typing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's in the manifests folder. Just above the java folder.